# An unstable 'date' code, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: matlab, date

I have a pretty straightforward code as follows,

```
[Y M] = datevec(datenum({'199812';'201203'},'yyyymm'));   
    % Y returns the # of years,
    % M is the # of months other                            
    % than a full year                                    
mns = diff([Y M])*[12;1];                                 
    % mns is the total # of months
    % between 12/1998 to 03/2012                          
Monthdate = cellstr(datestr(datenum(1998,12+(0:mns)',1),'yyyymm')); 
    % Returns cells as
    %199812,199901,199902,                                        
    %199003,...201203
```

Sometimes this code works well. Sometimes it returns,

```
Error using datenum (line 181)
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

How can it be unstable? Is there anyway to make it stable?

Comment: it works well for me (MATLAB R2011a x64 Windows)

Comment: You need to figure out what the arguments to datenum are when it is failing.  Then ask if there is still a question as to why.

Comment: Thanks for replys guys.  @Franck Dernoncourt, it works well sometimes. But the weird thing is that sometimes it doesn't work and I don't know why. @ mwengler, I got your point. I am goona dig more. Thanks

Comment: how often does the code crash?

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: This is the last solution from a MathWorks message board: "When I run the same program on another machine with MATLAB 2009b, there is no problem at all." Maybe add this thread to your watchlist? http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287922

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt. It's very unpredictable. I wrote a loop specifically testing it 1000 times, but nothing went wrong. But it did went wrong several times before.

Comment: @Victor Hugo. Mine version is 2011b

Comment: @kitchenette.Hmm, interesting. Looks like they had the same problem..

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt. It just happened again.

Comment: do you clear all every time you run your piece of code?

Comment: maybe `open datenum` might give you some ideas. `dtstr2dtnummx` is only used three times.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem (R2012a) - it really just seems to be an unstable function. Whenever it starts happening, I just restart Matlab and it works fine again for a while.